# How to solve a simple inequality

Tags: equation-solving

I am having trouble getting *Mathematica* to solve really simple inequalities.

I started with

```
Solve[{y^x >= 2*y - 1}, x]
```

but *Mathematica* can't solve it. So I tried

```
Solve[{y^x >= 2*y - 1, x > 10, y > 10}, x, Reals]
```

with still no luck. I tried `Reduce`, but that didn't work either.

An obvious solution is $x \geq \frac{\ln(2y-1)}{\ln(y)}$. How can I persuade *Mathematica* to give me that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to provide additional assumptions like in :

```
Reduce[{y^x >= 2*y - 1, y > 0, x > 0}, x, Reals]
```

Comment: Oh.. Reduce[{y^x >= 2*y - 1, y > 10, x > 10}, x, Reals] doesn't work but that does.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
Reduce[y^x >= 2*y - 1 && y > 0 && x > 0, x, Reals]
```

The result is
`(0 < y <= 1/2 && x > 0) || (1/2 < y < 1 &&  0 < x <= Log[-1 + 2 y]/Log[y]) || (y == 1 && x > 0) || (y > 1 &&  x >= Log[-1 + 2 y]/Log[y])`

Comment: How is this different in any way than the accepted answer?